# What's the simplest method to get an unknown array's length?

Tags: c++

I have a function which does some calculations on an array, but it has to know the array's size. How could I get that, if my function only has the array itself, without the size?

Is it possible to do that on multi dimension arrays?

Comment: What *kind* of array ? C-style, `std::array`, `std::vector`, or what ?

Comment: If you are using Microsoft Visual Studio you might want to have a look at [`_countof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Paul: I'd like to know the method with array, and vector, too. :)


Thank you Shaktal! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the possibility that you may be able to store the number of elements of the array in element 0, and the rest of them in the other elements.

Answer (score 7):

One approach is to use templates:

```
template <size_t N>
void foo(int (&array)[N]) {
    ⋮
}

int main() {
    int array[] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    foo(array);
}
```

Note that this only works if the caller knows the array's size at compile-time.

Answer (score 4):

Your question tagged as "C++", so the first rule is:

1. [**Arrays are evil!**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html) Don't use arrays if it possible. Use `std::vector` (or another container) instead.

   ```
   void Foo(const std::vector<int>& v)
   {
        size_t size = v.size();

   }
   ```

   But, if you **reeeeealy** must use arrays:
2. If your array allocated on stack and passed as array variable: you can use template trick

   ```
   template<typename T, size_t size>
   size_t GetSize(T (&arr)[size])
   {
        return size;
   }
   ```

   But it is a huge overkill: if you calling such function with different array sizes often, code bloating will be enormous.
3. If your array passed as pointer and has no documented "end of array" flag: impossible
4. If your array has "end of array" flag: count all elements until this flag. Null-terminated C-strings are good example:

   ```
   size_t strlen(const char *str)
   {
       size_t size = 0;
       while(*str++) 
          ++size;
       return size;
   }
   ```

*"Really must use arrays"*, means for example if you use some kind of library with C interface. Most of such libraries gives you array size along with a pointer to array data, or have *explicitly documented* convention on how to find end of such arrays (except C-strings. Everyone knows, they end with `\0`). Any of this methods are really unsafe.

BTW, have I mentioned already that arrays are evil? =)

Answer (score 2):

Without changing the signature of the existing function, the only solution is adding a "sentinel" element to your array - say, a number that may not be part of the legal portion of your array. Scan the array until you get to that sentinel, and count the elements. This would give you the length of the array. This approach is similar to what C strings do to determine length by adding null termination.

Of course in C++ you have a much better option than plain arrays: using `std::vector<T>` lets you avoid passing length, because `vector<T>` has `size()` function.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an ordinary C array which is allocated statically like this:

```
int a[5]
```

you can find the length by

```
sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])
```

This is, however, true only when you use this at the scope of the very "a" variable, and the length is essentially computed at **compile** time.

If you want to pass the array to a function with e.g. the following signature:

```
void f (int *arr)
```

then there is **no** way to find that length inside the function, as it takes generic pointers (or arrays) to int.

Answer (score 1):

Want you can also do and which is quite common in C. Pass the size of the array as argument to the function.

eg mutliply a vector with a scalar

```
void scalar_mutliply ( double* vector, double scalar, unsigned size ) {
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i ){
        vector[i] *= scalar;
    }
}
```

and to test it:

```
using namespace std;

int main ( ) {

    double vector [] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 };

    scalar_mutliply( vector, 2, sizeof(vector)/sizeof(vector[0]) );
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(vector)/ sizeof(vector[0]); ++i ){
        cout << vector[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which results in this output:

```
2
4
6
8
10
```